# Prov- or disproving $ \operatorname{ord}(gh)= $ $ \operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{ord}(g), \operatorname{ord}(h)) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove or disprove:

Let $ G $ be a group and $ g, h \in G $ be elements of finite order. Then $ \operatorname{ord}(gh)= $ $ \operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{ord}(g), \operatorname{ord}(h)) $.

I am not sure if it is correct or not. If it's true or false, how can I formally prove / disprove it?

Comment: I assume kgV refers to what is usually called "least common multiple" or LCM in English. I would change it that if so because this is an English site!

Comment: KgV is not a standard notation, is it Lcm(lower common multiple)?

Comment: Have u tried to verify this property in some well-known finite groups of small order?

Comment: I don't really understand the question since in another recent post, you manipulate permutations. Take the permutations of $\{1,2,3\}$ and $g=(1 2)$ and $h=(132)$.

Answer (score 3):

Another way yet to see this claim is false:

1. Let $\pi$ be any element of a group with $\pi \not = e$. Then $\operatorname{ord}(\pi) = \operatorname{ord}(\pi^{-1}) \not = 1$. What is $\operatorname{ord}(\pi\pi^{-1}) = \operatorname{ord}(e)$ though.
2. Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group on $\{1,2,3,4, \ldots, n\}$. Then $S_n$ is generated by the set of *transpositions*, and each transposition has order $2$. If this claim were true then, every element in $S_n$ would have order $2$.

Answer (score 2):

If $a$ and $b$ commute,  then we immediately get $\lvert ab\rvert \mid \rm{lcm}(\lvert a\rvert, \lvert b\rvert)$.  *Without* equality however. This is easy to see.

If $a,b$ do *not* commute,  then all hell breaks loose.  Consider a free product like $\Bbb Z_2*\Bbb Z_2$, for example.  Then one can produce $a,b$ of order $2$, with $ab$ of infinite order.

Comment: I dont think this is true though. What about $b=a^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Claim: Statement is false

Counterexample:

Let be $\sigma_1 = (1 2 34)(56) $ and $\sigma_2=(156)(234) $ $\in S_6$ and
$\sigma_1 \circ \sigma_2 = (16243)(5) \in S_6$.

It holds:

$ord(\sigma_1)=4$, $ord(\sigma_2)=3$ and $ord(\sigma_1 \circ \sigma_2) = 5$

$\rightarrow lcm(ord(\sigma_1), ord(\sigma_2)) = lcm(4,3) = 12$

$\Rightarrow ord(\sigma_1 \circ \sigma_2) = 5 \neq 12= lcm(ord(\sigma_1), ord(\sigma_2))$

-> Claim is true!

Answer (score 1):

The claim is false.

Take $g$ of even order and $h=g$. Then $\operatorname{ord}(gh)=\operatorname{ord}(g^2)=\operatorname{ord}(g)/2\ne \operatorname{ord}(g)=\operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{ord}(g), \operatorname{ord}(h))$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a set with at least four elements, and let $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$ be the group of all bijections $f:X\to X$. Every element of $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$ is the product of two elements of order $2$, but not every element of $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$ is of order $2$.